# Best Way Connect To Ms Sql

Tags: android

I have to use MS Sql Server and Android Devices for My Project.
What is the best way to Data Process for MS SQL and ANDROID

.NET WEB SERVICES or JTDS CONNECTOR and SQL QUERIES?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you create some kind of web service that acts as the bridge between your Android app and your database. Your android app sends some of type of request to your web service, the web service handles the request (query, insert, etc. to database) and then returns the result to the Android app, and then your Android app does something with the data.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I have another question :)
I have 30 android devices.if I update my program Do I have to install again again 30 devices or IS there another way?

Comment: As far as I know, yes. If you have a very fast computer, you could try to use AVDs instead. It really boils down to whether loading AVDs or plugging in each phone is faster for you.